# Django REST Framework Forbidden CSRF cookie not set

Tags: django, cookies, django-rest-framework

I have this view

```
from rest_framework import parsers, renderers
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import EmailUserSerializer
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='post')
class ObtainAuthToken(APIView):
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.JSONParser,)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        user_serializer = EmailUserSerializer(user)
        return Response({'token': token.key, 'user': user_serializer.data})


obtain_auth_token = ObtainAuthToken.as_view()
```

and this url

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$',views.obtain_auth_token, name='get_auth_token'),
    url(r'^login2/$',ObtainAuthToken, name='get_auth_token'),
]
```

i'm trying posting with postman like this:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/api/login2/
```

but i can only receive this error

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api/login2/
[02/Jul/2017 22:49:11] "POST /api/login2/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2891
```

I know there are hundreds of post like this, I searched for a long time a solution but nothing seems working

tryied like this

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^login2/$', csrf_exempt(ObtainAuthToken)),
    ...
)
```

this

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
class LoginView(APIView):
   @method_decorator(csfr_exempt)
   def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
       ...
```

and also this

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class LoginView(APIView):
       ...
```

and this

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='post')
class ObtainAuthToken(APIView):
    throttle_classes = ()
    ...
    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
```

Comment: Try `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='post')` -> `@csrf_exempt`... and see if that solves it?

Comment: Do you mean this?

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='post')
class ObtainAuthToken(APIView):
    throttle_classes = ()
    ...
    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        ...

still not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `ObtainAuthToken.as_view()`. Any `APIView` automatically uses `csrf_exempt()` (and explicitly checks the CSRF token if you're using `SessionAuthentication`), but that won't work if you're not using `.as_view()`. You don't have to explicitly use `csrf_exempt` on top of what `APIView` does.

I'm not sure why you're not using the first url, `/login/`, but if you're having issues with that url, you're going the wrong way fixing them.

On a side note: `csrf_exempt` sets an attribute on the function. As such, using it on `post()` has absolutely no effect, since the middleware won't check the attributes on the `post()` method. You need to use it on the `dispatch()` method or as `csrf_exempt(ObtainAuthToken.as_view())`.

Comment: That's actually save my day! 
btw im not using the first login because i was trying to implement a different version...now it works great thanks to as_view() ! thank you